# display the first specific element on whole page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to only display the first element and hide all other elements.

Here is an example:

```
<style>
    h1 {
        display: none;
    }

    h1:first-of-type{
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Test</h1> <!-- only this one should be visible -->
        123
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>ABC</h1>
        def
    </div>
</body>
```

Is there a solution without JS?

Comment: You want that to happen when something occurs?If yes **probably** you need javascript.If no I guess you could use `nth-child`

Comment: Well actually I need this for the printing few, because suddenly chrome is buggy

Comment: both h1 are visible, because they are both the first element in the div

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `:first-of-type` on `h1` would not work, instead use that on the first `.content`'s `h1`. Like so:

```
h1 {
    display: none;
}

.content:first-of-type h1 {
    display: block;
}
```

```css
    h1 {
        display: none;
    }

    .content:first-of-type h1{
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        123
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>ABC</h1> 
        def
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tsnj3qqx/)

```
.content ~ .content h1 {
    display: none;
}
```

This is by what I know the shortest solution, it basicly picks all h1 elements expect the first one.

**Explanation:**
~ picks all siblings (elements) after the first .content class which have the .content class

If you want to read further [W3 Schools with examples](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)[W3 sibling combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)